# ALSA errors when running pulseaudio examples

Tags: c, alsa, pulseaudio

The errors in question are these:

> ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
>
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
>
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

I've tried everything I can think of, including editing alsa.conf and uninstalling/reinstalling all related packages.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `dmix` is not PulseAudio. Anyway, nobody knows what exactly you're doing.

Comment: Could you please update this with your alsa opening section code? then may be we can help